# Form render failed because the user's session was closed

Tags: 2010, infopath, error

Suddenly one of the InfoPath forms on my company's Sharepoint site has stopped working. The log has the following message:

> Form render failed because the user's session was closed StackTrace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Controls.XmlFormView.RenderForm(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Controls.XmlFormView.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Controls.XmlFormView.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Controls.WebUI.BrowserFormWebPart.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, WebPart part)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChrome.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, WebPart part)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone.RenderZoneCell(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Boolean bMoreParts, WebPart part)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.WebPartInFieldHelper.RenderHtmlWithWebParts(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, SPChunkedStringBuffer bufHtml)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.RichTextField.RenderFieldForDisplay(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseFieldControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FormField.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EmbeddedFormField.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
>   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)      at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)

I Googled the error "Form render failed because the user's session was closed" and it actually returned ZERO results.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Is this when viewing an existing form or submitting a new one, or both?

Comment: Viewing an existing one (could be both but not tried making a new one)